# Variable is always nil (Codable)

Tags: swift, null, codable

here I come with some black magic !

I receive a JSON from a webservice so I have an object which map this JSON.

In my struct (which implements `Codable`) I have my `init(from decoder: Decoder)` and for an unknown reason, a property is always assigned to `nil` even if there is a value in my JSON.

My property : `public var bookingDate: Date?`

And the way we decode it : `bookingDate = try values.decodeIfPresent(Date.self, forKey: .bookingDate)`

We have custom date decoder :

```
public func getDefaultDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom { decoder in
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dateString = try container.decode(String.self)

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = Constants.Date.formatFull
        if let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
            return date
        }
        formatter.dateFormat = Constants.Date.formatDay
        if let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
            return date
        }
        formatter.dateFormat = Constants.Date.formatFullWithTZ
        if let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
            return date
        }
        throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container,
                                               debugDescription: "Cannot decode date string \(dateString)")
    }

    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

    return decoder
}
```

I have checked many times with breakpoints and the date I received is parsed. BUT ! `bookingDate` is always `nil` !!!

To try to figure out, I add those lines :

```
let test : Date? = try values.decodeIfPresent(Date.self, forKey: .bookingDate)
let test2 : Date = try values.decodeIfPresent(Date.self, forKey: .bookingDate)!
```

(I force cast because I know I got value in my case)

Scroll few lines below, add a breakpoint, hit run and with the help of my fellow debugger ...
  [image: Here comes the debugger]

I found that `test` is `nil` and `test2` isn't. There is something I don't understand. Did we something wrong ? Or is there a black hole which sucks the value and put it in an other universe ?

When I print variables, I got values for both !

```
test : Optional(2020-06-16 22:00:00 +0000)
test2 : 2020-06-16 22:00:00 +0000
```

Edit :

I got this in the JSON (it is very long and not pretty at all) :

```
{
   "booking_date": "2020-06-16",
   ...
}
```

Part of the struct (as long as the JSON):

```
public struct WSOffer : Codable {
   public var bookingDate: Date?
   ...

   enum CustomCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case bookingDate, ...
   }
}
```

What is happening guys !?

Comment: Show us the JSON and the actual object you are parsing please.

Comment: Probably the issue is related to something *asynchronous*. And if you *know I got value* why optional `Date?` and `decodeIfPresent`?

Comment: By the way, the debugger does not always show variable values correctly.

Comment: @vadian Just for my case I know we have a value but it could happen we don't

Comment: @vadian Ho damn I didn't know for the debugger ! I have to show the value in a view and I can't see it